# Capture jpeg images from RTSP - gStreamer

Tags: video-streaming, jpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I am builidng a video streaming pipeline. I want to capture thubmnails of video stream which is live. I have used `jpegenc` to encode buffer into `jpeg` and save it through a `filesink`. I dont want every frame to be saved, I want to save only 10th frame, (i.e modulo 10, this should be configurable). How can I do that? (The stream is coming from rtsp source)

Comment: Check upon `GstPadProbe`. With that you can decide whether to pass or drop decoded buffers downstream. Here you can do you decision based on modulo.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution might not be mathematically correct (e.g. to capture every 10th frame with 100% accuracy) but maybe it is worth mentioning. It is based on gstreamer's [videorate](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videorate/index.html?gi-language=c) element which can manipulate video FPS (frames per second).

Lets assume we you have **rtsp source** similar like this one:

*rtsp://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen03.stream*

(public camera, H264 video, framerate=60000/1001=~60 frames per second).

Pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen03.stream" \
! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 \
! timeoverlay halignment=right valignment=bottom \
! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=60000/1001 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location="./frame%08d.jpg"
```

should capture every received video frame and save it as jpg image.

But if you modify `viderate` caps like this

`video/x-raw,framerate=6000/1001`

rate of capturing frames will be ~6 fps (10 times less, theoretically every 6th frame should be captured).

So knowing input video's framerate you could modify `viderate` "output" caps to achieve the wanted "output" framerate.

**Note** that I added `timeoverlay halignment=right valignment=bottom`which will add pipeline running timestamp to video/jpg images for easier trace.